# iPhone URL Schema block safari error alert

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, url-scheme

I tried open my app if installed in iPhone from safari browser simply passing like `myApp:// using javascript document.location="myApp://";` if not redirect to another webpage to display app details. but when app not installed safari throw **"Cannot open Page"** alert ,if redirect to another webpage that time also safari alert box not dismiss automatically. 
    Any one help me to how redirect the webpage without safari cannot open page alert if app not installed on device.

My Code :
Simply html file and body `onload="checkdevice();return false;"`
display message in textarea `"document.getElementById('txtMsg').value"`

```
function checkdevice() Check browser detection
{
    if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/)))
    {

        document.getElementById('txtMsg').value ="Running on iPhone /iPod /iPad Device";
        checkAppExists();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('txtMsg').value ="Please run this page on iPhone / iPod / iPad Device";
        checkAppExists();
        return false;
    }
}



function checkAppExists() 
{

    var time = (new Date()).getTime();
    window.location="myApp://";
    setTimeout(function(){

         var now = (new Date()).getTime();

     if((now-time)< 400) 
         {
            window.location="http://mydomin.com/appdetails.html";
         }
       else
       {
            document.getElementById('txtMsg').value ="App Installed"; * App will launch here *
       }

    },300);

}
```

Comment: How can you solve this issue?